# How to get certificate from SSL_CTX?

Tags: ssl, x509

I used `SSL_CTX_use_certificate( SSL_CTX *ctx, X509 *x )` to store certificate to `SSL_CTX *ctx`.

It gets stored in `SSL_CTX` object at `ctx->cert->key->x509`

Is there any API to get back from `SSL_CTX` ?

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but post here for reference, as I lost some hours to resolve this question.

Here is an example of getting certificate from SSL_CTX*, and checking the remaining validity days (and seconds) of the certificate:

```
X509 *x509 = SSL_CTX_get0_certificate(ssl_ctx);
const ASN1_TIME* notAfter = X509_getm_notAfter(x509);
int remaining_days=0, remaining_seconds = 0;
int  result = ASN1_TIME_diff(&remaining_days, &remaining_seconds, NULL, notAfter);
std::cout << "remaining days: " << remaining_days << std::endl;
std::cout << "remaining seconds: " << remaining_seconds << std::endl;
```

It is using OpenSSL 1.1

Answer (score 0):

`X509 *SSL_get_peer_certificate(const SSL *ssl);` SSL_get_peer_certificate() returns a pointer to the X509 certificate the peer presented.

`X509 *SSL_get_certificate(const SSL *ssl);`  The function returns an  X.509 type pointer to the certificate loaded in the SSL structure.

The definition of the above is as simple as you mentioned in your answer

```
X509 *SSL_get_certificate(const SSL *s)
{
    if (s->cert != NULL)
        return(s->cert->key->x509);
    else
        return(NULL);
}
```

Below is the reference link for more information 
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/ssl.html

Comment: But i am working with context level... this you gave for connection object

Comment: is it not trivial ? you have the `SSL_ctx` object and the index where the `x509 *` certificate is, why do you need an API for that ? `SSL` session object on the other hand can get the certificate from the `SSl_ctx` object