# openssl API to extract the leaf certificate from a certificate chain available in SSL_CTX

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, tls1.2, x509

I am using OpenSSL API calls in my C program to establish Mutual-TLS connection to a remote server.

When establishing the connection, the client uses any X509 PEM certificate (i.e.self-signed, CA-issued leaf cert or a chained certificate) provided by the user.

I load the user-provided certificate to my SSL_CTX via call to: `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file ()`, which can load both single certificate or certificate chain.

My objective is to print the leaf certificate metadata in the prompt something like below:

```
% my_tls_client -key foo.key -cert foo.crt myserver.com:2566
Attempting to connect to server myserver.com port:2566
Using host certificate as follows:
    serial: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee
    subject: foo...
    valid from: DATE1
    valid untill: DATE2
    WARNING: The provided certificate is about to expire in X days !
    Connected to server successfully!
```

To do so, first I need to identify and fetch the leaf (host) certificate in X509_STORE available in SSL_CTX.

Is there any OpenSSL API that can get me the leaf certificate from the chain of certificates?

I came across a few approaches like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58559886/3050164
That suggests using: `SSL_CTX_get0_certificate()`, But I am unable to find any reference to this method in OpenSSL docs.

Also, another API: `X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert()`
This too does not seem to provide the leaf certificate specifically...

Answer (score 1):

The certificate used is specific to the SSL connection and not to the context (which can be used for different connections). The API you are probably looking for is [SSL_get_certificate](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/SSL_get_certificate.html).

Comment: That is not what I was looking for. I am looking to get the local certificate info and not remote peer certificate. I create the SSL_CTX and add the key and certificate (or chain) to the SSL)CTX. Then use the SSL_CTX to get a new SSL that I use to connect to server. I want to display the leaf certificate details that is already added to the SSL_CTX, but to do that I need to get the handle to the leaf certificate first...

Comment: @Anirban: *"... and not remote peer certificate"* - the __remote__ certificate is retrieved using SSL_get_peer_certificate. This here is about the __local__ certificate as also stated in the linked documentation.